# Spring boot custom validation

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I have a model object that it's validation requires some more sophisticated logic involving a call to a service component.
I tried to implement like this:

```
public class RequestModuleEntryValidator implements Validator {
    /*
     * A service
     */
    private final MyService myService;

    /*
     * Constructor for the module request validator
     */
    @Autowired
    public RequestModuleEntryValidator(MyService myService) {
        this.myService= myService;
    }

    /*
     * Checks if the validator supports the given class
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return RequestModuleEntry.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    /*
     * Validates the given module request
     * @param o The module request entry object
     * @param errors The errors object
     * @return Nothing
     */
    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
// Call to my service...
}
```

But I have the warning:

> Autowired members defined in invalid Spring Bean

So my question is how can I implement a custom validation, corresponding with the `@Valid` annotation when this validation has to call some service methods for deciding if the model data is valid...

Answer (score 0):

For creating a custom validator you can implement ConstraintValidator interface.

For that you need to create a custom annotation and annotate your model class with that annotation.

Then create your validator class **RequestModuleEntryValidator** which imlements ConstraintValidator interface and override isValid() method as below :

Your Controller method may look like this :

```
public ResponseEntity<AnyObject> controllerMethod(@Valid @RequestBody PojoObject) {
.....
}
```

Your Model Object will look Like :

```
@ValidPojoRequest // Custom Annotation
public class PojoObject {
 ....with all properties 
}
```

Custom annotation class will look like :

```
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PojoValidator.class)
public @interface ValidCancelRequest {
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  String message() default "{com.pojodetailvalidation.message}";
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And then your PojoValidator.java file will look as follows :

```
public class PojoValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPojoRequest,PojoObject> {

  @AutoWired 
  private MyService service;

  public boolean isValid(PojoObject request, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
   // Call to your Service and check whether all conditions satisfy and accordingly return a boolean value.
//You can also return a proper error message for a particular property in your Pojo class by adding below 
  context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("any message you wan to show to the one consuming your api").addConstraintViolation();
  context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
  return false;
  }
}
```

isValid() method returns a boolean if it returns false then validation fails

Comment: ConstraintValidator is not an option since it meant for more general purpose. In this case the validation logic is very specific to a certain class and it will be meaningless if it will be used on another class than it meant for. Validator can be implemented for a specific class...